# normalize date using the deprecated Time class

Tags: java, android

the following method is written using the deprecated android Time class

```
    // To make it easy to query for the exact date, we normalize all dates that go into
// the database to the start of the the Julian day at UTC.
public static long normalizeDate(long startDate) {
    // normalize the start date to the beginning of the (UTC) day
    Time time = new Time();
    time.set(startDate);
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(startDate, time.gmtoff);
    return time.setJulianDay(julianDay);
}
```

[you can find this method here at line 47](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/4.09_write_uri_matcher/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/data/WeatherContract.java)

please help me to understand it...

I tried different (unix, UTC) values for **startDate** argument such as 1464174000 and 1464433200 just to understand the output of the method but the method always return **1458000000** which is equivalent to:

**03/15/2016 @ 12:00am (UTC)**

[see the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djz2Z.jpg)

so what is the purpose of the method if it always return the same value ?

i want to understand it so that i can write it again with the GregorianCalendar class that is not deprecated

Comment: What do you mean you tried different values? Please [edit] your question to show what you did

Comment: call with this value 1464181063013

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#getJulianDay(long,%20long))

> Callers must pass the time in UTC millisecond (as can be returned by toMillis(boolean) or normalize(boolean)) and the offset from UTC of the timezone in seconds (as might be in gmtoff).

So `startDate` should be in millisecond, not in second. Call with proper value. For example-

```
public static long normalizeDate(long startDate) {
    // normalize the start date to the beginning of the (UTC) day
    Time time = new Time();
    time.set(1464181063013);
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(1464181063013, time.gmtoff);
    return time.setJulianDay(julianDay);
}
```

I hope it will give you a different result.

Comment: I believe the question asked how to additionally replace the usage of the Time class since it is deprecated

Comment: thank you...but i get an error (Integer number too large)

Comment: Documentation says they are long, so how did you get Integer number too large.

Comment: @EmdadulSawon sorry it was a mistake...i tried 1464181063013L and i get   1464123600000

Comment: So, please vote up and accept the answer if it works